# how i can create file "remotely" by vim

Tags: vim, ftp

i am new vim user

i cannot create file in my host by vim

i use `:ftp://user@machine/path`

i can connect in my host but i cannot create new file ???

another Q
when i open file how i can back in directory

note. i connect by c panel user and password  ,, how i can connect by ftp username and password

thank you and Sorry for my bad English

Comment: if your host is linux I suggest ssh access

Comment: What exactly did you mean by "how i can back in directory"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your remote file in Vim by typing:

`vim ftp://user@machine/path/filename`

in your command line.

Some things you might want to consider:

- If you are using a Unix-like OS on your client machine, you'll probably find it easiest to simply mount your FTP site to a local directory, and then create and edit your files with whatever you like, for example Vim.
- As one user suggested, if the host is Unix-like you can connect it via SSH and then edit files with Vim installed over there.

Comment: thank you goran now i can create file by use " % ", how i can use ssh and why ssh better than ftp

Comment: @tarek: It's not that it is better, it's just different. You usually use ftp to access files remotely. Well, with ssh you access a remote console, and do your stuff there. It's quite easier (at least to me) to open a console to a remote machine and use vim over there.